# How to use an external server with Ruby AMQP Carrot Library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amqp, carrot

I am using the Ruby AMQP Carrot library and I am trying to talk to a test RabbitMQ server on a virtual machine.  The AMQP port is open on the machine but I can't get Carrot to establish an external connection.  I have tried the following:

> Carrot.queue('message', :durable => true, :server => '192.168.162.176')
>
> Carrot.queue('message', :durable => true, :host => '192.168.162.176')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I talked with the Carrot developer and this is the answer he gave me and it works great:

```
@client = Carrot.new(
 :host   => host,
 :port   => port.to_i,
 :user   => @opts['user'],
 :pass   => @opts['pass'],
 :vhost  => @opts['vhost'],
 :insist => @opts['insist']
)

queue = @client.queue('foo')
```